# Nova get-password returns empty string

Tags: juju, maas, nova, quantum

I have a multi-host MaaS, Juju Openstack deployment. Each charm on different host, multiple nova-compute units (nodes). And Im using Quantum charm for networking.

When I attempt to retrieve the admin password for VM with the following command:

```
nova get-password <server> <privatekeyfile>
```

It returns an empty string.

I found that for this to work the HTTP metadata service needs to be up and running when the instance is booted up. So I installed nova-api-metadata package on compute-node where I will try to boot the VM. I restart all nova services on compute and controller nodes and i run the nova-api-metadata service.

It still return blank string.

Any suggestions on how to further troubleshoot this?

Somewhere i found that no other nova-api service should be running, somewhere i read that it should be specified in nova.conf file as enabled_apis.

Where the true is? What and where should be running and specified?

Comment: [Have you booted specifying a keypair?](http://www.cloudbase.it/openstack-windows-server-2012-r2-evalution-images/)

Comment: Also, *nix is forgiving. Backup and experiment :D

Comment: Do you get data if you query the HTTP metadata service directly? Also, is the ssh key password-protected?

Comment: If you mean if i can access http://169.254.169.254/openstack nop i can not.

Comment: So the metadata service is not running or a firewall rule is in your way.